Is it possible to make a procedural circular-streaks noise texture?
I have a circular metal rail object, and I want to add random streaks of high and low roughness along its top surface to suggest uneven wear from the wheels riding on it.
Plugging the Object vector of a Texture Coordinate node into a Vector Math > Length node and the output of that into the vector input of a Noise Texture node generates rings that are random radially, but perfectly uniform circumferentially - they all go entirely around the object and are the same width throughout.


Is it possible to make circular streaks that have random lengths, and widths that vary along their length?

If you combine length as X and angle as Y (atan2 of separated Y / X from the coordinates), you can use a 2d noise and stretch Y as you wish

Make polar coordinates (radius and angle) and stretch the angle / compress the radius.

Radius = length
Angle = atan2 of y / x



This is perfect, thank you!
